# Google Maps API in a for loop, how to incorporate a info window?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

So I have 4 maps all together on one page. I have them all working through the for loop. Now I need to add markers/ Infowindows any idea the best way to add that into the loop, thanks!

```js
// array of lat and lng locations
let locations = [
    {
      lat:-33.91722,
      lng:151.23064
    },
    {
    lat:22.3193,
    lng:114.1694
    },
    {
    lat:22.3255,
    lng:114.3532
    },
    {
    lat:23.3532,
    lng:115.1234
    }
];
let elements = ['maps', 'map-rec-one', 'map-rec-two', 'map-rec-three']; // array of html element ids

window.addEventListener('load', 
function() {
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    initMap(locations[i], elements[i]);
    console.log(elements[i]);
    console.log(locations[i])}
}, false);

function initMap(location, element) {
    console.log(location)
    console.log(element)
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(element), {zoom:4, center: location});
}
```

Comment: Yes.  There are lots of ways to do that.  What  markers do you want to add?  Are they specific to the map?  Multiple markers on each map?  How is the information for the infowindow represented?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: So I want all the maps to look the same, they need markers in quite a few locations and each marker needs an info window. But I am a little stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add the information for the markers to your array.

(if you want the same markers on each map, you can simplify the array or have a separate array for the markers)

```
let locations = [{
  lat: -33.91722,
  lng: 151.23064,
  markers: [{
      lat: -33.91722,
      lng: 151.23064,
      info: "this is a marker at -33.91722,151.23064"
    }, {
      lat: -33.8722,
      lng: 151.03064,
      info: "this is a marker at -33.8722,151.03064"
    },
    {
      lat: -33.5722,
      lng: 151.03064,
      info: "this is a marker at -33.5722,151.03064"
    }
  ]
},
{
  lat: 22.3193,
  lng: 114.1694,
  markers: [{
    lat: 22.3193,
    lng: 114.1694,
    info: "this is a marker at 22.3193,114.1694"
  }]
},
{
  lat: 22.3255,
  lng: 114.3532
},
{
  lat: 23.3532,
  lng: 115.1234
}
];
```

Then in your initMap function, add those markers to the map:

```
  function initMap(location, element, infowindow) {
    console.log(location)
    console.log(element)
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(element), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: location
    });
    if (location.markers) {
      for (var i = 0; i < location.markers.length; i++) {
        createMarker(location.markers[i], map, infowindow);
      }
    }
  }
```

createMarker function:

```
  function createMarker(location, map, infowindow) {
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
      infowindow.setContent(location.info);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    })
  }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bvozju0p/4/)

[image: screenshot of multiple maps with markers]

**code snippet:**

```js
// The following example creates complex markers to indicate beaches near
// Sydney, NSW, Australia. Note that the anchor is set to (0,32) to correspond
// to the base of the flagpole.
function initialize() {
  // array of lat and lng locations
  let locations = [{
      lat: -33.91722,
      lng: 151.23064,
      markers: [{
          lat: -33.91722,
          lng: 151.23064,
          info: "this is a marker at -33.91722,151.23064"
        }, {
          lat: -33.8722,
          lng: 151.03064,
          info: "this is a marker at -33.8722,151.03064"
        },
        {
          lat: -33.5722,
          lng: 151.03064,
          info: "this is a marker at -33.5722,151.03064"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      lat: 22.3193,
      lng: 114.1694,
      markers: [{
        lat: 22.3193,
        lng: 114.1694,
        info: "this is a marker at 22.3193,114.1694"
      }]
    },
    {
      lat: 22.3255,
      lng: 114.3532
    },
    {
      lat: 23.3532,
      lng: 115.1234
    }
  ];
  let elements = ['maps', 'map-rec-one', 'map-rec-two', 'map-rec-three']; // array of html element ids

  window.addEventListener('load',
    function() {
      for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        initMap(locations[i], elements[i], new google.maps.InfoWindow());
        console.log(elements[i]);
        console.log(locations[i])
      }
    }, false);

  function initMap(location, element, infowindow) {
    console.log(location)
    console.log(element)
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(element), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: location
    });
    if (location.markers) {
      for (var i = 0; i < location.markers.length; i++) {
        createMarker(location.markers[i], map, infowindow);
      }
    }
  }

  function createMarker(location, map, infowindow) {
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
      infowindow.setContent(location.info);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    })
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#maps,
#map-rec-one,
#map-rec-two,
#map-rec-three {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Complex Marker Icons</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="maps"></div>
  <div id="map-rec-one"></div>
  <div id="map-rec-two"></div>
  <div id="map-rec-three"></div>
</body>

</html>
```